# What does the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property" JS error mean?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain to me what these errors mean?

I need the answers for a school project.

```
Error 1 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null"
Error 2 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null"
```

Comment: You try to read some properties from a variable that is `null`. Don't you get more information in the messages, like line numbers or file-names? If you are getting them in a browser, all modern browsers have inspectors with good debuggers, try to use them.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you are trying to use a property on something that is **null**. Make sure you have an object to operate on before trying to use the property. I.e `getBoundingClientRect` expects a dom element.

One way to select a dom element is by id:

`var element = document.getElementById('myElement');`

[More about selecting dom elements here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors)

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot !